# Xenomorphs spreading by infection from adult xenomorphs?

Tags: alien-franchise, xenomorph, alien-covenant

In Covenant we see a particularly insidious way for xenomorphs to propagate. In any book, etc. is it suggested that adult xenomorphs might reproduce by shedding viral/nanoparticles similar to what we see in Covenant and sort of also as shown in Prometheus?